# How to show custom content on <iframe> if URL didn't load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, iframe

I have an `<iframe>` that displays cross domains pages. Some sites work, some don't. 
I don't want the `<iframe>` to display the default error page (different for each browser) when the URL doesn't load for any reason.

[image]

I want to display a custom content.

**Already tried/searched:**

1. `<iframe>` doesn't trigger any error event, so javascript `<iframe onerror=="callback">`  doesn't works.
2. cross domain request with ajax will return fail with statuscode = 0, so `$.get(url).then().catch()` doesn't works.
3. I can test the URL in the server side, but question is for client side.
4. `<iframe onload="callback">` doesn't give any information about loading the URL properly, just the DOM element.
5. Can't access the `<iframe>` inner content, when it's cross domain, due to security features in all browsers.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I understand you didn't tag this with `php`, but a backend language can help here. Add a backend script, such as some php, inside your iframe source file to detect if the URL is valid, and then display content accordingly:

```
//iframe src

<?php

    $headers = get_headers($iframeURL);

    if (strpos($headers[0], "404") !== false) {

        $HTML = $customContent;

    } else {

        $HTML = $standardContent;

    }

?>

//in iframe document body

    <body><?php echo $HTML ?></body>
```